# Getting an occasional error calling WebServices

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, web-services

I have a ClickOnce app that calls WebServices on the server (standard ASMX style, not WCF).  Occasionally, the users get this error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
> An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.
> Check InnerException for exception details.
>
> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connect request was made on an already
> connected socket

This occurs fairly rarely (10-20 times a day out of nearly a million calls), but still enough that users complain about it once in a while.

The server is a standard Windows 2003 R2 with IIS.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Without seeing the code ot config it's hard to pinpoint it, but it seems to be executing a http call on a channel already doing a call.

You could also implement a retry logic when this error occurs, so that the users are not affected by it. You could also try to set the KeepAlive property to false on your webservice calls.

Comment: what is that inner exception? maybe some conflicts in dll versions during serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that you implenting the a Using Statement around your call, there client handles only six threads out, this could cause the webservice to refuse the call.

```
using (var proxy = new ApplicationWebService.ApplicationWebService())
{
    proxy.Method();
}
```

If this does not work, you may want to think about calling the webservice via aync.

Cheers